# How to assign single port into multiple vlans

Tags: cisco, ios, switch

I have cisco switch 3560 and want to create vlans where in i can have a single port in multiple vlans. I tried creating one port e.g fa0/23 as trunk and then allowed it through multiple vlans but it doesnt work. The said port fa0/23 is not traceable through vlans.

```
**Example of what i am looking to establish.
Vlan 1  : fa0/1 , fa0/2 , fa0/23
vlan 2 : fa0/3, fa0/4,fa0/23
vlan 3 : fa0/5,fa0/6,fa0/23**
```

The Switchport multi command is not working on this switch which i always execute on cisco catalys 3500xl

Answer (score 4):

Probably you already know this, but I'm pointing it out anyway.

As Radius said, you can configure a single port in trunk mode; but this means ***tagged*** 802.1q Ethernet frames will be sent to that port, so you will need to connect to it something which can succesfully decode and detag them (like a trunk port on another switch, or a trunk port on a ESX host).

You ***will not*** be able to simply connect a computer's NIC to that port and have it connect succesfully to any one of those three VLANs. That would require 802.1q support ***on the computer itself***.

Comment: 802.1q support is available on most linuxes, (and some windows systems, apparently).  I use it regularly on my laptop to connect to a half dozen different VLANs

Comment: @Tom, that's exactly what I said ("That would require 802.1q support on the computer itself."); but you wouldn't be able to simply connect an Ethernet adapter to such a port and assign an IP address to it, without quite some additional configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if the 3 vlans are active on the switch (sh vlan to see that):

```
Interface fa0/3
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,3
```